# Android: get checked items name from customised list with check box

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have list view.For that each row i customized as text view and check box.Now i want to get the name of checked items.I tried to use the checkedItemPositons but that is not working is that is because of 2 layouts??

I want to delete the checked itmes when delete button is pressed.How can i do this?
Here my code

```
      public class ManageLikes extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ListView lv;
Button btndelsel, btndelall;
CheckBox chk;
HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mCartItems = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

List<String> likes = new ArrayList<String>();
//DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.managelikes);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    //String data[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    likes = db.getAllLikes();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    btndelsel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndelsel);
    btndelall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndelall);
    btndelsel.setOnClickListener(this);
    btndelall.setOnClickListener(this);

    lv.setCacheColorHint(0);

    LayoutInflater mLInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final LAdapter adapter = new LAdapter(getApplicationContext(),likes, mLInflater);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int count = likes.size();
    String checked = "";

    if (v == btndelsel) {
        //i want delete the checked items here
    }


    if (v == btndelall) {
        //delete all items

    }
    }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach.

1. Inside adapter have a listener for check box, And keep track of checked items in some sort of data structure upon check box click listener.
2. Upon click of delete button remove the appropriate data from your data source i.e. database by using data structure keeping track of checked items.
3. After deletion Update the adapter by calling notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the UI.

Comment: Do *not* put a signature/tagline (i.e. "cheers") in your posts, as per the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/FAQ#signatures.  Also, do *not* put a link to your site in all of your posts, again, as per the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/FAQ#promotion - Continuing to do so will lead to further moderator action.